# How to split data in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Let's say....there is a column with data, "A, B, C" in SQL Server 2005. How can i split the data in that column into something like..

```
Column A
--------
A  
B  
C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in SQL split function.  You can either do it in another language that's accessing the DB, or you can write a T-SQL split function like [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itai/archive/2009/02/01/t-sql-split-function.aspx).